# Using lstlisting with T2A

Tags: listings, font-encodings, cyrillic

I would like to display a code listing using the package `listings`. It all work nice, except if I had the fontenc T2A. When I do, the listing stop being displayed using `\ttfamily` font and is shown using regular font.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}        %T2A causes a problem...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings}
%\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{pcr} 
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true,keepspaces=true,columns=flexible,
  aboveskip=6pt,belowskip=6pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
GRD
  /SUBJECTSPERGROUP equal = 1000
  /WSFACTORS X (2)
  /SCORES population = "RV.MVN({0,0}, {5**2,.99*5*5;.99*5*5,5**2})"
  /CONTAMINANTS population = "RV.MVN({-5,5}, {1**2,-.01*1*1;-.01*1*1,1**2})" PROPORTION = .5.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Remove T2A in the fontenc package call, and everythings work fine. Put it and the font is no longer `\ttfamily`.
I tried renewing the command `\ttdefault` (see commented line), but to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: `courier` doesn't support the `T2A` encoding. You could add `\fontencoding{T1}` to the `basicstyle` (provided your listings don't contain any Cyrillic).

Comment: As simple as that! `\lstset{
  basicstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily,...}` indeed solved my problem. Thanks @Robert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no support for the `T2A` encoding with the `courier` font, so LaTeX will fall back to Computer Modern Roman. If you don't want to use a different typewriter font, and provided that the code listings don't contain any Cyrillic, you can switch to `T1` encoding for the listings:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily,
        ...
       }
```